# Interpreting Cisco logging symbols

Tags: cisco-ios, logging

When I issue a "show logging" command to see the locally buffered logs, the log statements are displayed sometimes with an asterisk in front of the date and sometimes with a period in front of the date and sometimes with neither (see below).

> 000046: *Apr 22 13:05:46.064 MDT: %DUAL-5-NBRCHANGE: EIGRP-IPv4 666: Neighbor 10.1.2.3(Serial0/0/0:0) is up: new adjacency
>
> 000068: .Jul 17 08:16:52.399 MDT: %DUAL-5-NBRCHANGE: EIGRP-IPv4 666: Neighbor 10.1.2.3 (Serial0/0/0:0) is down: interface down
>
> 000083: Jul 17 09:40:41.060 MDT: %DUAL-5-NBRCHANGE: EIGRP-IPv4 666: Neighbor 10.1.2.3(Serial0/0/0:0) is up: new adjacency

What do these symbols mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If nothing is before the date, it means that your router clock was set manually or is in sync with a NTP server by the time of the log.

If with an asterisk, it means you didn't set the clock or it isn't synced with a NTP server.

If there's a period, it means the clock was in sync but the NTP server is not accessible.

[Source](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fundamentals/command/reference/cf_book/cf_s2.html#wp1486074)